# Proper setup when finding all eigenvalues of a matrix A

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have a matrix $A$, that we want to find all Eigenvalues for.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    4    & -1\\
    2    & 1  \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$

What's the proper setup to begin this? I know it looks something like:

$(4-\lambda)(1-\lambda)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to solve the 'characteristic equation'

$$\det(A-\lambda I)=0 ,$$

where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

In your case you solve

$$(4-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-(2)(-1)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks. I got $\lambda$ = 3 and $\lambda$ = 2, does that look right?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 0):

Find the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}4-\lambda&-1\\2&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$